# How To Get The Redirected URL From Original URL Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, redirect

## How Can I Get The Redirected URL From Original or Short URL?

for example:

```
    URL_1 (Short URL) = "http://af.ly/FQhAo"
```

This will redirect to

```
    URL_2 (Original URL) = "http://download.bitdefender.com/windows/desktop/t_security/2013/en-us/bitdefender_ts_2013_32b.exe"
```

So how can we get URL_2 From URL_1? help Please.
(I have googled but not found any solution)

Project Information:

- Platform: Visual Basic Express 2010
- .NET Framework Version: 2.0

Thanks For Your Time.
**Edited:**

I just have one URL which is URL_1, and I want to get the URL_2 with the help of URL1.

See The Image below, How a famous Software getting URL_2 (which is 100% unknown string) From URL_1 (which is short URL and Known) instantly. I want to do same in my program in visual basic .net.

[image: See This Image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Problem is now solved, thanks to google and [Daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/397434/how-to-get-redirected-url-as-string-after-request)
here is solution

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("Your short URL here"), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim resUri As String
        response = req.GetResponse
        resUri = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
        MsgBox(resUri)
```

this will return URL_2.

Comment: Is it just me or is the line that says `Dim Res As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()` redundant and unused?

Comment: req.GetResponse() is used after at         response = req.GetResponse

Comment: You could simplify this: `Dim resUri As String = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("url here"), HttpWebRequest).GetResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the original URL as a query string parameter? i.e. in url_1, redirect to: `http://pastehtml.com/view/b95qx66rc.html?redirectfrom=http://goo.gl/ouCeb`

Then in url_2 use this code:

```
Dim OriginalURL As String = request.querystring("redirectfrom")
```

Comment: `Dim OriginalURL As String = request.querystring("redirectfrom")`
ERROR: "request is not declared."
**I just know URL_1, And I want to Know URL_2 with the help of URL_1.**

Comment: I have add an image, Which helps you to understand my question. @w0051977

Answer (score 0):

URL_2 = "http://" & URL_1 & "/view/b95qx66rc.html"

Comment: Ooohhh!!! As I say **I Don't Know even one letter of URL_2**, So From where I get "/view/b95qx66rc.html"???
It's not a solution, I thing The solution is HTTPrequest but HOW?

Comment: I have add an image, Which helps you to understand my question. @iDev