# Capture all intermediate Urls before the final/landing URL using HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, response.redirect

I have a URL which redirects to several URLs before reaching the landing page. I found the solution to get the final redirect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622297/how-to-get-the-redirected-url-from-original-url-visual-basic-net) but I want all the intermediate URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
'http://tinyurl.com/gtrp -> points to google.ca
Dim urls As List(Of String) = GetAllRedirectURLs("http://tinyurl.com/gtrp")
'urls(0) = "http://google.ca"
'urls(1) = "http://www.google.ca/"

Private Function GetAllRedirectURLs(path As String) As List(Of String)
  Dim urls As New List(Of String)
  Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(path)
  request.Method = "HEAD"
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = False
  Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
  If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Moved Or response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect Then
    Dim redirectsToURL As String = response.GetResponseHeader("Location")
    urls.Add(redirectsToURL)
    urls.AddRange(GetAllRedirectURLs(redirectsToURL))
  End If
  Return urls
End Function
```

Used recursion to drill down and collect links. Based off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704956/897326).